# How to set flag for specified Object from another Object of Other Class?

Tags: java, oop

Please help me with object-oriented programming. 
I have a class **Main Class** where I created a *Client* object (instance) of class **Class Clients**. 
After that, I created object *Adress* (instance)  of **Class Adresses** in the **Main Class** .

One Client has several Addresses, but only one address can be basic(main).

Question: how to set for existing object *Client* that it has already the main address. I need to do it from Adress object because there is some logic for selecting main adress in Adress object.
Thank you.

Comment: Showing code might help you out.

Comment: You should not select the main address in the `Address` class, but from the `Client` instead. What if you would be using the `Address` class in more contexts? Let the consumers of such class wrap their own logic around the address list.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to add a

> for existing object Client that it has already the main address

with the focus on *Client* object, one solution can be the [Decorator_design_pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm). Since it allows you to attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality too. You can consider the following participants in your implementation:

```
public abstract class Component{}
```

(AddressableObject)
defines the interface for objects that can have responsibilities added to them dynamically.

```
public class ConcreteComponent{}
```

(Person)
defines an object to which additional responsibilities can be attached.

```
public abstract class Decorator extends Component {}
```

(Decorator)
maintains a reference to a Component object and defines an interface that conforms to Component's interface.

```
public class ConcreteDecorator extends Decorator{}
```

(BasicAdress)
adds responsibilities to the component.